# Freetype correct positioning of letters and undestanding freetype FT_Face parameters

Tags: c++, freetype

Im using Freetype for rastering text into a image, im getting the letters correctly but Im not taking into account if the letters should be putted lower than the "normal" level. Is there any parameter in the `FT_Face` of Freetype that tells me this.

Here is an example of the normal raster (correct) and mine.
[image]

Comment: would that be the `bitmap_top` variable in [`FT_GlyphSlot`](https://freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#ft_glyphslotrec) ?

Comment: Yeah thats it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `bitmap_top` variable in the [`FT_GlyphSlotRec`](https://freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#ft_glyphslotrec). It tells you how many pixels above the baseline the top of the glyph should be.

There are more layout-related variables in FT_GlyphSlot so you might want to make sure you're not ignoring any that you should be paying attention to, such as the `advance`, which tells you how many 1/64ths of pixels you should move to the next glyph, and the `bitmap_left`, which (I think) tells you how many pixels to the right of the glyph position the bitmap should start.